# EC2 Scalable environment sending mail from instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, scalability, instance, postfix-mta, email-spam

I have an scalable environment on amazon cloud. I want to send emails (transactional, mailing) from EC2 instances.

I am using one elastic Ip for my load balancer. I have installed postfix on all my instances.

Now, I got mail from amazon saying this
"You recently reached a limit on the volume of email you were able to send out of SMTP port 25 on your instance:"

1) Do I have to use any mail service provider to send mails (eg: http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)?
2) I googled it, people suggesting to send request to amazon through this link
https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

If I have go with 2nd option, Do I have to take another elastic ip?

Could somebody explain me the proper way to send request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent request to Amazon. They have removed the limit.